# What is the purpose of closing, when compared to deletion?

Tags: support

With me being a relative newbie to Super User, I am trying to understand how the system works.

As per [the SU FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), questions have to meet certain standards, and that low quality ones will be closed. I understand that we need these standards in order for Super User to be a high quality Q&A site.

**What I want to know:**

- How does closing ensure higher quality posts? Closed off-topic questions, for example, only clutter up search. Why don't we delete these instead of closing them?
- And when is is appropriate to delete a question?

Comment: If it can be found by using search, it will hopefully prevent the next guy from asking the same off-topic question, especially if it's not *that* obvious that the question is not desired. That's also why we don't delete duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why don't we delete these instead of closing them?

- To serve as an example of what is off-topic here. The rationale is that people who see off-topic questions closed remember them and don't ask any off-topic question. The same goes for "bad" questions (i.e. "not constructive" ones).
- For historical purposes (some people really *want* these to stay, which would lead to delete-undelete wars)
- As a stage prior to deleting (e.g. you can go through all the "Not a real question" questions and delete them sooner or later)
- etc.

> And when is is appropriate to delete a question?

When it is …

- absolutely off topic
- insulting, offensive
- spam
- not valid anymore
- of really bad quality
- etc.

The reasons vary here.

---

See this blog entry for more details:

> ### [The Stack Overflow Question Lifecycle](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/)
>
> #### Why do you allow content to be deleted?
>
> Just like death is an unfortunate but normal part of life, I believe deletion is also an unfortunate but normal part of living websites.
>
> …
>
> #### Why would you delete a question? Isn’t closing it enough?
>
> - Some questions are of such poor quality that they cannot be
>   salvaged. They’re literally nonsense. Not every byte of data that is
>   created in the world is infinite and sacred.
> - Some questions are so incredibly off topic that they add no value to
>   a programming community.
> - The mental cost of processing these closed questions is not zero,
>   particularly for users who are actively engaged and scanning questions
>   to find things they can help answer.
> - If users see a lot of closed questions, they’ll note that we don’t
>   enforce the guidelines, so why should they? Without any final
>   resolution, asking questions that get closed becomes something we are
>   implicitly encouraging — a broken windows problem. If this goes on for
>   long enough, we’re no longer a community of programmers who ask and
>   answer programming questions, we’re a community of random people
>   discussing.. whatever. That’s toxic.
> - If enough of these closed questions are allowed to hang around, they
>   become clutter that reduces the overall signal to noise ratio — which
>   further reduces confidence in the system.

Comment: I suppose it is just the way it is, but I don't fully understand why you would let some of the faulty content exist to serve as an example.

A new user likely isn't going to search before posting, and therefore would not encounter the content, which is viewed as unwanted.

If said user would post a question, which is unwanted, doesn't that just lead to more clutter instead of education? He would only learn when the faulty question would get closed.

Comment: I know – it's not only new users though. Even long-time users repeatedly ask off-topic questions. Most of the "not constructive" / "not a real question" ones will eventually be deleted anyway. As Daniel said above, the duplicates are kept though.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.